# What does "a certain way' modify in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> I think chewing on a leaf **a certain way** is flirting.

Is it modifying "is," suggesting 'in a certain sense' or 'to some degree,' or is it modifying "chewing," implying 'in a particular manner'?

Comment: "A certain way" is a noun phrase functioning as a modifier in clause structure, i.e. it's a modifier in the VP "chewing on a leaf a certain way".

Comment: @BillJ Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"a certain way" modifies **the manner or style** in which the chewing on the leaf is done, suggesting that there is *a specific or unique way* of chewing on the leaf that is being referred to, which the speaker believes is a form of flirting.

Comment: @Thank you very much.

Comment: https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fc8.alamy.com%2Fcomp%2F2NYG3KK%2Fportrait-close-up-of-a-young-cynomolgus-monkey-holding-a-green-leaf-in-its-mouth-in-the-background-diffuse-light-shining-leaves-and-a-wooden-fence-2NYG3KK.jpg&tbnid=tygk07GpZL1H7M&vet=12ahUKEwirpIzrvbGBAxV0VDUKHb58AKkQMygLegQIARBl..i&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.alamy.com%2Fstock-photo%2Fleaf-eating-monkeys.html%3Fpage%3D3&docid=EAFdf-0wdKrV5M&w=1300&h=956&q=monkey%20chewing%20on%20a%20leaf&ved=2ahUKEwirpIzrvbGBAxV0VDUKHb58AKkQMygLegQIARBl  Flirtation in the wild.

Comment: @TimR Thank you very much.